# Simplest way to retry SQLite query if DB is locked?

Tags: python, sqlite

I as not quite sure where to ask, I hope it is right here.

What I search for is the simplest solution to retry a SQLite query if the DB is busy.
I use quassel as my IRC client on an server and I want to move old logs to a separate DB to keep the one it uses small.
The script I wrote to do that is:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE delfrom (id integer,val integer);
ATTACH '/home/irc/oldlog.db' as log;
BEGIN IMMEDIATE;
REPLACE INTO delfrom (id,val) select 1337,messageid from backlog where time < strftime('%s', 'now','-14 days') ORDER BY messageid DESC LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO log.log (messageid,time,bufferid,type,flags,senderid,message) SELECT messageid,time,bufferid,type,flags,senderid,message FROM backlog WHERE messageid < (SELECT val FROM delfrom where id=1337);
DELETE FROM backlog WHERE messageid < (SELECT val FROM delfrom where id=1337);
PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;
COMMIT;
```

And I run it using sqlite3 quassel-storage.sqlite < movelog.sql

The problem is, since quassel is running while this executes, sometimes the `BEGIN IMMEDIATE;` fails because the DB is locked.

Can someone suggest me an easy way to change that setup so the query is just retried every few seconds until it works?
I read that the python SQLite wrapper has that built in? Is there a special way I have to activate this, and more important, can I attach the second DB using python?
There is a timeout parameter to `sqlite3.connect` but I am not quite sure how that works. Does Python lock the whole DB for writing on every connect?

I am in no way fixated to using Python. The solution I'd prefer would be that sqlite3 returns 0 when this error occurs and then just wrap it in an loop in the shell, but that seems not to work.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `BEGIN INMEDIATE;` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python will retry regularly if the *table* is locked. It will not retry if the *Database* is locked.  Table locks are only propagated inside the same process, by se of threads, shared connections or other methods.

Database locks result when multiple processes write to the file, and (put simply) exist as long as the Journal exists.

To avoid this, the WAL mode can be used for journalling. ( pragma journal_mode=wal; )

To spin on database locks, you need to wrap the execute function with something like this:

```
for x in range(0, timeout):
  try:
    with connection:
      connection.execute(sql)
  except:
     time.sleep(1)
     pass
  finally:
     break
else:
    with connection:
        connection.execute(sql)
```

The last connection block will make it return exceptions properly.   This should be improved by checking the exception for database locked and otherwise raising the original exception, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What is the purpose of retry "later" for a commit that sould `BEGIN INMEDIATE;`, being processed/commited before all other commits in journal ?

Btw, this seems a good way to avoid data loss for this kind of commits.

I don't really see the need to use `BEGIN INMEDIATE;` without a method that ensures the retry if something fails. In theory, the SQlite journal will try those commits too, so i can't see how we need to implement our own retry loop.

Answer (score 16):

Use WAL mode for Sqlite, if you version is greater than 3.7 https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(DB, **kwargs)
connect.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL")
```

According to documentation "WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently."

Comment: Should be noticed that [WAL does not work over a network filesystem. All processes using a database must be on the same host computer](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: @davidlatwe for that kind of scenario a message queue (0mq, rabbitmq, etc) would perform better. Question, did you tried over sshfs too?

Comment: @erm3nda sorry, I haven't :)

Answer (score 10):

The SQLite library itself will retry regularly, if you have set the timeout high enough.

In the default Python wrapper, this is the second parameter of [sqlite3.connect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect).

Comment: should that retry also work when using the sqlite3 executable? Because as it seems it isn't!

Comment: The `sqlite3` executable doesn't use Python. But can can execute a [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) in there.

Comment: Actually while setting the timeout parameter will certainly help in many circumstances, it doesn't work the way you think. It sends the timeout value as a "sqlite_busy_timeout" call to sqlite3, which sets a busy handler. I.e., it is sqlite itself that is retrying the query until the timeout expires. Additionally, the busy handler is _not_ called if sqlite3 detects the concurrent access to the database is deadlocked.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon What else could I have meant with "the SQLite library itself"? And deadlocks are not possible with BEGIN IMMEDIATE.

Comment: the default busy handler by sqlite is a bit goofy, it has a non jittery sleep (all processes sleep the same amount of time) ... that can starve processes: https://sqlite.org/src/artifact?name=8983b4a3&ln=1657